# React Native onPress unable to trigger while other process is running

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using FlatList to render my list, each list item is clickable; however, when I click the item, it does not work until everything is loaded.

It seems like while the other items are still rendering, you can not perform an action or event until everything is fully loaded.

Here is my code:

```
return (
      <FlatList
        refreshing={this.props.refreshLoading}
        horizontal={false}
        initialNumToRender={20}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={20}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
        numColumns={2}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
        bounces={true}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item}
        data={userList}
        renderItem={(item) => {
          return (
            <UserCard
              index={item.item[1]}
              userInfo={item.item[1]}
              contentSize={this.state.contentSize}
              navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
          )
        }}
        onEndReached={this.onLoadMore}
        onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
      />
    );
```

Is there a proper way to handle it?

Answer (score 2):

This is because the Javascript thread is blocked by the rendering on the screen. Once the render of the batch of rows is complete then it will open up the thread for the click event. This rendering happens in batches, which can be tweaked.

See [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18135) issue on Github.

Basically you can play with the `initialNumToRender` and `maxToRenderPerBatch` parameters on the list until you get something that works for you, and doesn't look jumpy when rendering (it will render the list incrementally which might look weird if the values are too low - called fill rate).

You can read about these parameters in the react-native docs:

[initialNumToRender](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist.html#initialnumtorender)

[maxToRenderPerBatch](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist.html#maxtorenderperbatch)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, I will look in to these links . . be right back